# How does one go about writing a simple WYSIWYG editor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

In my project I need to write small WYSIWYG editor (just let users make text bold/italic/underline and maybe some more). So I wouldn't like to use monsters like tinymce or fckeditor. My question is what HTML elements and javascript functions do I need to know for it? An HTML element in which I can edit and format text is a very interesting thing in this question.

Comment: You're going to have a hard road ahead of you if you'd like to support multiple browser engines. [This talk (1h31m in)](http://www.livestream.com/alohaeditor/video?clipId=pla_b330ae0c-5e55-49ff-85ce-6a844b1566fa&utm_source=lslibrary&utm_medium=ui-thumb) by Norbert Pomaroli from the Aloha Editor Team goes into some of the gotchas. How did you manage btw?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to roll your own, look at [Midas](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html).  It's available in FF3+, IE, Safari, Opera, Chrome.

Basically, you use contentEditable and execCommand to turn the browser into an RTE.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('edit').contentDocument.designMode = "on";
```

Have a look at http://www.mozilla.org/editor/ie2midas.html

Answer (score 2):

There is http://www.gosu.pl/steditor/ which code is quite simple and clear. It uses designMode and execCommand as was mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use simple languages like markdown or textile and provide a live preview.

I think most people will get *asterisks for emphasis* and **double ones for bolding**.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)'s wysiwyg editor in the past and it lets you configure the the buttons so you could easily use it and limit the buttons to bold/italic/underline.